# Javascript merge two array

Tags: javascript, arrays, storage, local

I have two array.They looks like

```
var productId = [2,3,5];
var quantity = [10,13,15];
```

Now I want to merge these array in one array and store in local storage.New array looks like

```
var newArray = [2 =>'10',3=>'13',5=>'15'];
```

Comment: what's this? ```['2'=>10,'3'=>13,'5'=>15]``` makes no sense. can you post your expectation and what you've tried so far

Comment: You can't have an array with key value pairs in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You can create object instead using `Object.assign` and `map` methods.

```js
var productId = [2,3,5];
var quantity = [10,13,15];

var obj = Object.assign({}, ...productId.map((e, i) => ({[e]: quantity[i]})))
console.log(obj)

// localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(obj))
// console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')))
```

Or you can use `reduce` method instead of `map`.

```js
var productId = [2,3,5];
var quantity = [10,13,15];

var obj = productId.reduce((r, e, i) => (r[e]= quantity[i], r), {})
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: A quick and dirty performance test showed that `reduce` is quite a bit faster; on 20.000 iterations, `reduce` took ~10ms, whereas `Object.assign`+`Array.map` took ~28ms

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you want to merge two arrays with same length such that merged array will have keys from first array and values from second array. But unlike php, JavaScript doesn’t have concept of array with key and value pairs. What you can do is create a merged object with key value pair.You can achieve by creating a custom function which does that. So, the code for it would be something like:

```
let arrayA = ["name", "address", "phone"]; 
let arrayB = ["Niraj", "Kathmandu", "98423232223"];

function array_combine(a, b)
{
    if(a.length != b.length) return false; 
        let combObj = {};

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)  
        {
           combObj[a[i]] = b[i];
        }

        return combObj;
}
  let combined_obj = array_combine(arrayA, arrayB);
  console.log(combined_obj);
```

You can directly use reduce method of ES6 as well for the purpose.

```
let arrayA = ["name", "address", "phone"]; 
let arrayB = ["Niraj", "Kathmandu", "98423232223"];

    let combined_obj = 
     arrayA.reduce((obj, k, i) => ({...obj, [k]: arrayB[i] }), {}));
```

If you now want to store the combined_array in local storage, you can do that, by first stringifying it and then store it.

```
    let combined_obj = JSON.stringify(array_combine(arrayA, arrayB)); 
    localStorage.setItem('combinedObj', combined_obj);
```